# SharePoint 2013 Weekly Report on Pending/Approved/Rejected Items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, reports

Is it possible to get a SharePoint Designer Workflow to email Weekly Reports on how many items are Pending/Rejected/Approved.

I have tried the Alert Me function but it seems a bit too plain.

Our Client has asked us to try generate a weekly or even monthly report on how many items were Approved/Rejected and are still Pending at the end of every week or every month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you use 2013 workflow?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean? I am familiar with the 2013 SharePoint Designer Workflows yes, but just wanted to know if it was at all possible to generate a weekly/monthly report using a workflow? Or is there a more complex way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding:

It is possible using 2013 workflow. Pause your action for a week and loop it. So that you action first executes at the end of the week and it repeats for every week since it is inside a loop.